# Replace string com itens de um objeto

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer o `replace` de uma string, semelhante a que está no exemplo, nela tenho curingas `${}` e dentro dele tenho aqueles que seriam a chave de um objeto para substituição.

Dado esta explicação, qual seria a melhor opção para fazer esta substituição ?

```js
    let string = 'PP24,260:AN7'+
    'BARSET "QRCODE",1,1,11,2,1'+
    'PB "${qrcode}"'+
    'PP 270,265'+
    'PT "${cliente}"'+
    'PP 270,225'+
    'PT "${comprimento}"'+
    'PP 270,185'+
    'PT "${diametro}"'+
    'PP 270,145'+
    'PT "${espessura}"'+
    'PP 270,105'+
    'PT "${aco}"'+
    'PP 270,65'+
    'PT "${peso}"'+
    'PP 550,145'+
    'PT "${lote}"'+
    'PP 550,105'+
    'PT "${ordem}"'+
    'PP 550,65'+
    'FT "Swiss 721 BT",11'+
    'PT "${data}"'+
    'LAYOUT RUN ""'+
    'PF'+
    'PRINT KEY OFF';
    
    let obj = {
      qrcode: "asd1231",
      cliente: "1321384a684a654a564z6",
      comprimento: "1256.2",
      diametro: "13.5",
      espessura: "26.5",
      aco: "3695z",
      peso: "165.00",
      lote: "65zxc651z3x1",
      ordem: "5as651651",
      data: "2018-01-23"
    };
    console.log('res', string, obj)
```

Estou tentando fazer desta maneira

```
for(item in obj){
  console.log(item, obj[item]);
  console.log(string.replace(new RegExp('${'+item+'}', 'g'), obj[item]));
}
```

Percorro todas as chaves do objeto e para cada chave faço o replace, porem testa forma não está funcionando, tambem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar uma função como segundo parâmetro de [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

Ela receberá como argumentos:

- `match`: a string casada na RegExp
- `g1, g2, g3, ...`: os grupos cadados na RegExp, pode ser de `0` a `N`, depende apenas da sua RegExp.
- `offset`: a posição na string em que foi achado a substring que casa com a RegExp
- `string`: a string completa

Então uma solução poderia ser, criar uma RegExp que casa com `${...}`, agrupa o que estiver dentro das chaves, testa se existe no objeto e substitui o conteúdo.

Ex.:

```
string.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g, (match, group, offset, string) => {
    return group in obj ? obj[group] : match
})
```

A regex vai casar com `${...}` sempre agrupando o que estiver em `...` e dentro da função testo se existe a chave no objeto. Se houver é substituído, senão mantém a mesma string.

---

Exemplo rodando com seu código:

```js
let string = 'PP24,260:AN7'+
    'BARSET "QRCODE",1,1,11,2,1'+
    'PB "${qrcode}"'+
    'PP 270,265'+
    'PT "${cliente}"'+
    'PP 270,225'+
    'PT "${comprimento}"'+
    'PP 270,185'+
    'PT "${diametro}"'+
    'PP 270,145'+
    'PT "${espessura}"'+
    'PP 270,105'+
    'PT "${aco}"'+
    'PP 270,65'+
    'PT "${peso}"'+
    'PP 550,145'+
    'PT "${lote}"'+
    'PP 550,105'+
    'PT "${ordem}"'+
    'PP 550,65'+
    'FT "Swiss 721 BT",11'+
    'PT "${data}"'+
    'LAYOUT RUN ""'+
    'PF'+
    'PRINT KEY OFF';
    
let obj = {
    qrcode: "asd1231",
    cliente: "1321384a684a654a564z6",
    comprimento: "1256.2",
    diametro: "13.5",
    espessura: "26.5",
    aco: "3695z",
    peso: "165.00",
    lote: "65zxc651z3x1",
    ordem: "5as651651",
    data: "2018-01-23"
};

let x = string.replace(/\${([^}]*?)}/g, (match, group, offset, string) => {
  console.log(`
    match: ${match}
    group: ${group}
    return: ${group in obj ? obj[group] : match}
  `);
  return group in obj ? obj[group] : match
})

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso nativamente usando [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) do Javascript. Para isso, você vai trocar as `'` da String por ` e acessará diretamente as propriedades do seu objeto dentro da template string:

```js
let obj = {
      qrcode: "asd1231",
      cliente: "1321384a684a654a564z6",
      comprimento: "1256.2",
      diametro: "13.5",
      espessura: "26.5",
      aco: "3695z",
      peso: "165.00",
      lote: "65zxc651z3x1",
      ordem: "5as651651",
      data: "2018-01-23"
    };

let string = `PP24,260:AN7
    BARSET "QRCODE",1,1,11,2,1
    PB ${obj.qrcode}
    PP 270,265
    PT ${obj.cliente}
    PP 270,225
    PT ${obj.comprimento}
    PP 270,185
    PT ${obj.diametro}
    PP 270,145
    PT ${obj.espessura}
    PP 270,105
    PT ${obj.aco}
    PP 270,65'+
    PT ${obj.peso}
    PP 550,145
    PT ${obj.lote}
    PP 550,105
    PT ${obj.ordem}
    PP 550,65
    FT "Swiss 721 BT",11
    PT ${obj.data}
    LAYOUT RUN ""
    PF
    PRINT KEY OFF`;

console.log('res', string, obj);
```

Veja que fica bem elegante a criação da string, pois não é mais necessário se preocupar em concatená-la e em substituir marcadores de valores de variáveis.

Comment: Sim, temos alguns problemas com esta abordagem.

1º - Esta string vai está no banco de dados.
2º - Preciso que tenha o " " por questão de ser uma string na linguagem direct print

Comment: Ahh, coloca esse detalhe na pergunta, faz toda a diferença então. E adiciona a tag do direct print, pois sem ela a solução seria puro javascript, como eu indiquei.